# Add css class to rails link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to style a rails link using css using the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Learn More", :controller => "menus", :action => "index", :class => "btn btn-inverse" %>
```

I would expect that this would create a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="menus/" class="btn btn-inverse">Learn More</a>
```

Instead, rails is rendering this -

```
<a href="/menus?class=btn+btn-inverse">Learn More</a>
```

Has anyone else had this problem / know what I'm doing wrong? I know I can avoid this problem by manually creating the anchor tag rather than using helper, but I was wondering if there was a way to pass the css class info to the helper itself. I'm using Rails 3.2.6.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens with :class => ["btn", "btn-inverse"] or :class => %w"btn btn-inverse" ?

Comment: You could also just use `menus_path` as the second argument to `link_to` instead of specifying the controller and action.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You have a syntax problem. Try this instead:

```
<%= link_to "Learn More", {controller: "menus", action: "index"}, class: "btn btn-inverse" %>
```

[Some documentation for you to go further with the link_to Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

They say:

> *Be careful when using the older argument style, as an extra literal hash is needed:*
>
> ```
> link_to "Articles", { :controller => "articles" }, :id => "news", :class => "article"
> # => <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
> ```
>
> *Leaving the hash off gives the wrong link:*
>
> ```
> link_to "WRONG!", :controller => "articles", :id => "news", :class => "article"
> # => <a href="/articles/index/news?class=article">WRONG!</a>
> ```

---

I recommend you to **use the URL helper** generated following your routes configuration. In your case:

```
link_to "Learn More", menus_path, :class => "btn btn-inverse"
```

A little reminder on the Helpers generated:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users

# any view/controller
users_path #=> /users
edit_user_path(user) #=> /users/:id/edit
user_path(user) #=> /users/:id  (show action)
new_user_path(user) #=> /users/new
```

Comment: Ah, I was missing that hash. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: yeah, I know - it makes you wait a few minutes from when you ask the question. two more minutes!

Answer (score 5):

Try new argument convention:

```
<%= link_to 'Learn More', 'menus#index', class: 'btn btn-inverse' %>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you do not have a controller action / route necessary for the link, you can pass nil as the placeholder and get the classes to apply as necessary

```
<%= link_to 'link verbiage', nil,  class: 'classes for action tag'%>
```

Comment: The case for this is when you are over riding the click event with something like Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by the way

```
<%= link_to image_tag("imageexamplo.png", class: 'class or id examplo css'),{controller: "user" , action: "index"}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it using another view engine, *HAML* just in case a fellow developer is having this need

```
%i= link_to "Add New Blog Post", user_post_edit_new_url(current_user), :class  => "fa fa-plus-circle"
```