# Rails link_to interpreting :class and :style as params for the :action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, css

Here is the offending line:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Job Type template', :action => :jt_template, :style => "color:white", :class => "btn btn-primary" %></p>
```

And when we load the page and inspect the element:

```
<a href="/generals/jt_template?class=btn+btn-primary&amp;style=color%3Awhite">Job Type template</a>
```

Why are my class and style tags being interpreted as params for the action?

Other than this weirdness - it's working as expected.

Just FWIW - the jt_template action sends the CSV file as a download.  I was linking directly to the file stored in my public dir, but I found that when you clicked the button in Safari it would just open the CSV in the browser, and I'm forcefully required to make the file download instead (even though a user could get from the opened page)

EDIT:

Ever do that thing where you post to SO, then think of some new wording you haven't Googled, then find your answer on the first result?

[Add css class to rails link_to helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016295/add-css-class-to-rails-link-to-helper)

Someone go ahead and post the answer "you should put your :action inside { } and it will work" and I'll accept that.

Comment: you can add that as an answer and accept it. of course, it would help if you also add the link

Comment: Yup, you can answer your own questions. It's only fair, it's you who found the answer before anyone else could submit.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Job Type template', {:action => :jt_template}, :style => "color:white", :class => "btn btn-primary" %></p>
```

:action and :controller must be placed between { } in order to avoid the incorrect interpolation of stuff that comes after it (I only tried with :class and :style, but I assume it would affect anything that follows)