# Rails link_to URL and HTML options with remote: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, link-to

My current link

```
link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil, :search => nil), {class: css_class}
```

I want to add `remote: true` into the mix but when I encapusulate it with the `params.merge` (i.e. `{params.merge(), remote: true}` I get a syntax error. In rails I need to encaps the url options and the html options separately right?

`title` and `css_class` are both variables inside the helper method this link is in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016295/add-css-class-to-rails-link-to-helper/13016309#13016309 : `link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use:

```
link_to 'title', params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil, :search => nil), {class: css_class}, :remote => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil, :search => nil), class: css_class, remote: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5, `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from Hash, in an attempt to discourage people from using Hash-related methods on the request parameters without explicitly filtering them.

As part of this pull request, which was backported into Rails 5.1 and partially into Rails 5.0, an exception is raised if you try to call `to_h` on the parameters object without calling permit.

Calling `merge` on the original params object (`params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil)`) returns a new `ActionController::Parameters` object with the same permitted status (that is, permit has not been called on it). The `link_to` method then ends up calling `to_h` on that object, which raises the exception.

If you know which parameters should be allowed in the link, you can call permit with those listed.

```
params.permit(:param_1, :param_2).merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil)
# OR
params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil).permit(:param_1, :param_2, :sort, :direction, :page)
```

If you don't know which parameters could be included in the link, then it's possible to call `request.parameters.merge(...)` (as mentioned in this answer) or `params.to_unsafe_h.merge(...)`. However, as pointed out in comments, this is a security risk when the result is passed to `link_to`, as a parameter like host would be interpreted as the actual host for the link instead of a query parameter. There are several other keys that also have special meaning in link_to (everything accepted by url_for, plus :method), so it's generally a risky approach.